# Web service/Client transaction properties

Tags: service, web, client, transactionloganalysis

I have developed a SOAP-based web service and also a REST style web service using either xml or JSON format. I used java to implement the web services.

Is there any software you can recommend to test transaction times, file transfer times etc between clients and the web services?

I'm looking for processing reasons to choose either SOAP or REST.

Is there a simulator that I could use to mimic multiple clients?
If I create my own client application, is there some way of detecting transaction times without a simulator?

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to only test the time required to process, I would suggest instead of using a simulator or third party tools you could do it simply by logging messages.

Use log4j logging in your application, to log request received, request completed, total time required in your application. It should work fine and provide you with the results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I take it I can use log4j for glassfish. Also, do you have any links on log4j setup?